# Count number of substrings having only vowels

Tags: c, string, algorithm, substring, c-strings

I wrote a code to find the vowel substrings of the given substring. but i need help in counting the substring thus formed?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

void substr(char str[], int low, int high)
{
    printf("%.*s \n\n", high-low+1, (str+low));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    char str[] = "aeixae";

    int length = strlen(str);

    int start_index = 0, end_index = 0;

    for (int x=0; x<=length; x++) {
        if (x == length || !isVowel(str[x])) {
            end_index = x;
            substr(str, start_index, end_index - 1 );
            start_index = end_index + 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes u can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isVowel( char  c) 
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    return strchr( vowels, c ) != NULL;
}

void output_substring( const char *s, int n )
{
    printf( "%*.*s\n", n, n, s );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "aeixae";
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( const char *p = s; *p != '\0'; )
    {
        while ( *p != '\0' && !isVowel( *p ) ) ++p;

        if ( *p != '\0' )
        {
            ++count;
            const char *q = p;

            while ( *p != '\0' && isVowel( *p ) ) ++p;

            output_substring( q, p - q );
        }
    }

    printf( "There are %zu substrings\n", count );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
aei
ae
There are 2 substrings
```

Another approach is to use standard C functions `strcspn` and `strspn` instead of the while ;loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void output_substring( const char *s, int n )
{
    printf( "%*.*s\n", n, n, s );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "aeixae";
    size_t count = 0;
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    for ( const char *p = s; *p != '\0'; )
    {
        p += strcspn( p, vowels );

        if ( *p != '\0' )
        {
            ++count;
            const char *q = p;

            p += strspn( p, vowels );

            output_substring( q, p - q );
        }
    }

    printf( "There are %zu substrings\n", count );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

Comment: but there are more substrings there  a,e, i, a, e, ae, ei, ae, aei

Comment: @P__J__ As I have understood the assignment there are two sub-strings.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there are much more substrings.

Here you have "bruteforce naive" version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

bool onlyVovels(const char *p1, const char *p2)
{
    while(p1 <= p2) 
    {
        if(!isVowel(*p1++)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void printSubstr(const char *start, const char *end)
{
    while(start <= end) putchar(*start++);
    putchar('\n');
}


int countAndPrint(const char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    const char *start = str, *end = str;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(*++end);end--;
        for(start = str; start <= end; start++)
        {
            for(const char *cend = start; cend <= end; cend++)
            {
                if(onlyVovels(start, cend)) 
                {
                    printSubstr(start, cend);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        printf("Number of vovel only substrings: %d\n", countAndPrint(argv[1]));
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/DiK_MV

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *only count* the vowel substrings, you can just keep track of start index of where we found a vowel and keep adding the distance from first found till current index as it's count.

**For example:**

Let's take `aeixae`. Our current for loop `i` variable is at `0`.(Substrings to be considered are marked with `-` lines).

> ```
> a e i x a e
>
> -
> ```

- Here,  `start_index` is `0`. So, count is `i - start_index + 1`(+1 to include the single character vowel too as it is a substring of length 1)
- `i` becomes `1` in the next iteration. Now, we would consider substrings as follows:

> ```
> a e i x a e
>
>   -
> ---
> ```

- So, we add 2 to count as we have 2 substring only vowels.
- `i` becomes `2` in next iteration. Substrings to be considered are:

> ```
> a e i x a e
>     -
>   ---
> -----
> ```

- Now, when `i` becomes `3`, we get an `x` character to process which is **not** a vowel. So, we just reset `start_index` to `-1` as it broke the chain now. Calculation goes on for the rest of the string in the same way.

**Snippet:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool isVowel(char c) {
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}

long long int countAndPrint(const char *str)
{
    long long int count = 0,i;
    int len = strlen(str);
    int start_index = -1;
    for(i=0;i<len;++i){
        char c = tolower(str[i]);
        if(isVowel(c)){
            if(start_index == -1) start_index = i;
        }else{
            start_index = -1;
        }

        if(start_index != -1) count += (long long int)(i - start_index + 1);
    }    
    return count;
}


int main()
{
    printf("Number of vowel only substrings: %lld\n", countAndPrint("aeixae"));
}
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/RKhjR7

- Time complexity is **O(n)** and space complexity is **O(1)**.